# Python callback for custom button

Tags: python, bokeh

In a python script, I generate the HTML code for a table with a lot of buttons. The table, including the buttons, is incorporated into a Div widget (by using its 'text' attribute). I did it this way instead of using Bokeh's 'Button' class because the buttons need to be included in this highly customised table, and I think this would be hard to accomplish using Bokeh's built-in layout classes.

Since my buttons are just html code inside a Div widget, I can't use Bokeh's on_click method to attach a python function to my custom buttons.

How do I best add Python callbacks to my custom buttons? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are asking for a Python callback while you are generating something what to me looks like a stand-alone HTML ?
So what I think that you need is a JS callback which is in fact a standard JS function but additionally with access to all Bokeh models objects.
So for the JS callback you could create the shadow Bokeh Button objects that you bring into your global JS scope using the Bokeh `get_model_by_name(<model_name>)` function after the page init and use those Bokeh models for your needs in your JS functions. You just need to assign to every Bokeh model a `name` attribute.

See example below made for Bokeh v2.1.1

```
import os
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS, Row
from bokeh.util.browser import view

button11 = Button(label='Button11', button_type = 'danger',  name = 'Button11', visible = False)
button12 = Button(label='Button12', button_type = 'success', name = 'Button12', visible = False)
button21 = Button(label='Button21', button_type = 'primary', name = 'Button21', visible = False)
button22 = Button(label='Button22', button_type = 'warning', name = 'Button22', visible = False)

template = """
{% block postamble %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function button_alert(btn){
            alert(btn.name + ' = ' + btn.button_type)
        }
    </script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="button_alert(btn11)">B11</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="button_alert(btn12)">B12</button>
            </td>            
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick='button_alert(btn21)'>B21</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick='button_alert(btn22)'>B22</button>
            </td>            
        </tr>         
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(init, 100)          
        });

        function init() {
            btn11 = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('Button11')  
            btn12 = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('Button12')  
            btn21 = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('Button21')  
            btn22 = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('Button22')             
        }
    </script>
    
{% endblock %} """

save(Row(button11, button12, button21, button22), template=template)
view(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.basename(__file__)).replace('.py', ".html"))
```

Result:

[image]